# How to place the text to the right of the first input, and make the text near the second input wider?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I use Bootstrap 4.

**BC is the world leader in online news and information and seeks to inform, engage and empower the world.**  - should be to the right of the top input.

[image]

**775 Downstreet Rd APT C7 Brooklyn, NY, 112009**  should look like this:

[image]

And a screenshot of my markup:

[image]

Comment: Try `align-items: flex-end` For us to properly find a solution you will have to provide more code. Please see here [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: place the class `col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12` on  `<fieldset id="edit-about-company">` tag.

Comment: @Kameron And for which class do you need the css code? In my screenshot, all the classes related to this part of website.Tell me exactly what you need to add and I will add.

Comment: @sumeshsn1 Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @antongordon25 Glad, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the class name to the pointed fieldset tag, hope this help

[image]